# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have a question…

I’ve programmed these:

```
# Dependencies
import pandas as pd
from numpy import where
from matplotlib import pyplot

# Load Data
names = [“Frequency”,”Comments Count”,”Likes Count”,”Text nwords”]

dataset = pd.read_csv(“Posts.csv”, encoding=”utf-8″, sep=”;”, delimiter=None,
names=names, delim_whitespace=False,
header=0, engine=”python”)

X = dataset.values[:,0:2]
y = dataset.values[:,3]
# Explore Data
print(dataset.shape)
print(dataset.head(10))
print(dataset.describe())
print(dataset.dtypes)

X,y = dataset(n_samples=100, n_features=4, n_informative=4, n_redundant=0, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=4)

# create scatter plot for samples from each class
for class_value in range(3):
# get row indexes for samples with this class
row_ix = where(y == class_value)
# create scatter of these samples
pyplot.scatter(X[row_ix, 0], X[row_ix, 3])
# show the plot
pyplot.show()
```

**I’m getting this error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File “C:/Users/USER/pythonProject/main.py”, line 44, in

X,y = dataset(n_samples=100, n_features=4, n_informative=4, n_redundant=0, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=4)

TypeError: ‘DataFrame’ object is not callable
```

Any ideas? What can I do?

I think the problem is about the "load data". How can I insert my own dataset?

Thank you in advance!!

Sofia

Comment: The error appears to be on Line 44 (or line 21 of your posted code) Where are you getting `n_samples`, `n_features`, `n_informative`, `n_redundant` or `n_clusters_per_class` from?  It doesn't seem to be part of the Pandas DataFrame.  Can you provide a single row example of your CSV input?

Comment: @MattB The first row of my CSV:                                                  
10;4290;148663;150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this:

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv(“Posts.csv”, encoding=”utf-8″, sep=”;”, delimiter=None,
names=names, delim_whitespace=False,
header=0, engine=”python”)
```

You are creating a pandas DataFrame that is read from the CSV file and stored in the variable named `dataset`.

Later, you are trying  to call `dataset` and pass a bunch of arguments to it:

```py
X,y = dataset(n_samples=100, n_features=4, n_informative=4, n_redundant=0, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=4)
```

But since `dataset` is a pandas DataFrame object and not a function, you can not call it that is why you are getting error.

You probably want to call some other function that will take those parameters and return back a tuple of two values that you are trying to assign to `X` and `y` variables.